# How to start shell script with arguments in new terminal window

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, arguments

I tried to run shell script in new terminal window, from mac osx. I use open cmd like this and it works fine
`open -a Terminal script.sh`

My issue is I have to pass arguments in my shell. I tried 
`open -a Terminal script.sh arg`
`open -a Terminal script.sh --args arg`
`open -a Terminal --args script.sh arg`
`open -a Terminal "script.sh arg"`

But nothing is working !!!
Do you know a way to do that?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found something. I don't like this but it works:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd ${Dir} && ./script.sh ${arg}"'
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `sudo bash /path/to/script -option1 -option2`(if your script needs `sudo`) or `bash /path/to/script -option1 -option2`(if no `sudo` is needed) from the terminal?

Comment: Hello, 
Thanks for your answer.
this command works but I need to open script in a new Terminal, and not in the current terminal. I think Applescript do the job but is slow to execute.